# How to check if there are only spaces in string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8

```
print_r(strlen(trim('     ')));
```

the result is 9

I also tried

```
preg_replace('/[\n\r\t\s]/', '', '   ')
```

but the result is not zero.

**Please download my code and you will get the result**

http://blog.eood.cn/attachment.php?id=70

Comment: Your two attempts don't even make sense, nor do your results. Trimming that first string should result in an empty string (length 0). preg_replace is for replacing strings, not checking if they exist.

Comment: sorry for the error in title.

Comment: @Bruce: on my install : `print_r(strlen(trim('     ')));` = 0 wondering how you get 9!

Comment: `echo strlen(trim('     '));` prints `0`.

Comment: i copied the code from this page, the reuslt is zero.
may be the space is different. But i don't know why my result is not zero of my code.

Comment: Please download my code and you will get the result

Comment: No, `print_r(strlen(trim('     ')));` prints `0` as well.

Comment: @Bart: you downloaded and runed my code?

Comment: Your code does not contain the same as you posted here, the tested string in the code in your zip file is ` |  `, which should evaluate to `1`, not `9`.

Comment: @soulmerge: but i copied the code here. And i can see nothing of the space.

Comment: @bruce, no I did not download and execute your code (which is something I rarely do), nor will I do so. I executed what you posted, which prints `0`, as already stated.

Comment: You have an extra character in your code that's the problem (and that's why is important to look at the source in unicode problems Bart), i updated my response with it.

Comment: @pablasso: no, I disagree. *I* should not be the one looking at the contents of some zipped file hosted somewhere else. Bruce should post the relevant part of his not-working code here on SO.

Comment: @Bart: But i can not post it here, how to attach a file here?

Comment: I don't see why you can't post it. Copy-paste does not work? If you mean that the code is too long, simply copy-paste the relevant part.

Comment: If the characters are messed up or converted, then say so in the post.

Comment: @Bart K. Your thought is so simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$s = '     ';
if (strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/u','',$s)) == 0) {
    echo "String is empty.\n";
}
```

If that doesn't work i suggest doing this

```
$s = '     ';
if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/',' ',$s))) == 0) {
    echo "String is empty.\n";
}
```

These solutions have been tested on different platforms.

The u [flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) tells preg_replace() to treat the string as a multibyte string, namely utf-8

The character is a nonbreaking space C2A0 and can be generated with alt+0160.

Comment: Can you download my code and check the *space*, i think it is not normal space.

Comment: Note that `empty` also returns *true* for `"0"`.

Comment: You may need to specify the internal encoding.

Comment: there was one non breaking space in your code, but the preg_replace would convert them all to regular space and then trim can take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the fastest way is to trim leading spaces ([`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) will fail fast if there are other characters) and compare the result to the empty string:

```
# Check if string consists of only spaces
if (ltrim($string, ' ') === '') {
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are doing something else that is messing up the results? Your test do returns 0

```
print_r(strlen(trim('     ')));
```

And that's the expected behavior of [trim](http://www.php.net/trim).

> This function returns a string with
>   whitespace stripped from the beginning
>   and end of str . Without the second
>   parameter, trim() will strip these
>   characters:
>
> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary    space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line    (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage    return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical    tab.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at your attached code i noticed you have an extra character between 2 spaces.

This is the output of **hexdump -C**

```
$ hexdump -C  space.php 
00000000  3c 3f 0d 0a 70 72 69 6e  74 5f 72 28 73 74 72 6c  |<?..print_r(strl|
00000010  65 6e 28 74 72 69 6d 28  27 20 c2 a0 20 27 29 29  |en(trim(' .. '))|
00000020  29 3b 0d 0a 3f 3e                                 |);..?>|
00000026
```

And this is the output of **od**, with just that character in the file.

```
$ od space.php 
0000000    120302                                                        
0000002
```

trim won't delete that space, because.. well, it's not a space. [This is a good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261253/how-do-i-figure-out-what-this-character-is) on how to spot unusual characters.

Oh, and to answer your updated question, just use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as Peter said.

Answer (score 2):

A simple preg_match() would suffice:

```
if(preg_match('/^\s+$/', $str)) == 1){
 die('there are only spaces!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the `count_chars` function](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_count_chars.asp) or [the `substr_count` function](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_substr_count.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if a string contains a space?

```
if(strpos($string, ' ') !== false) echo $string.' contains a space';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)...

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $str);
```

Or this...

```
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " ", "\o", "\xOB"), '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen(trim($_POST['foobar'])) == 0){
 die('the user didn\'t input anything!');
}
```

[`empty`](http://us.php.net/empty) would also make it

like

```
$bar = trim($_POST['foobar']);
if(empty($bar)){
 die('the user didn\'t input anything!');
}
```

Comment: I cannot get the empty statement to run, what's the deal with that?

Comment: Ah, you have to assign the trimmed string to a variable before using empty.

Comment: Beware to empty(): empty('0') returns True as well!

Answer (score 0):

if ***trim($var)*** is not working then $var may be not a string.
so first cast into string

**$var1 = string($var)**
and then
***trim($var1)***.