# If string only contains spaces?

Tags: php, string

How can i check to see if a string **only** contains spaces?

Comment: *Any* whitespace or just spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if there are only spaces in string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754393/how-to-check-if-there-are-only-spaces-in-string-in-php)

Comment: `substr_count($str, ' ') === strlen($str)`

Comment: @caw Best answer! The question asked for a way to detect if a string only contains **spaces**, most answers check if string only contain **whitespace character(s)**.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
if (strlen(trim($str)) == 0)
```

or if you don't want to include empty strings,

```
if (strlen($str) > 0 && strlen(trim($str)) == 0)
```

Comment: I'd say `if (strlen(trim($str)) != strlen($str))`

Comment: @voyager: that would determine if the string had _any_ leading or trailing spaces, the question is does it have _only_ spaces.

Comment: @voyager: What about `"  hello world  "`? In that case `strlen(trim($str))` is 11 and `strlen($str)` is 15, but the string is not *only* made up on spaces.

Comment: Point taken, but it would have to be `if ((strlen(trim($str)) != strlen($str)) && (strlen(trim($str)) == 0))` if you want to make sure that the string contains only whitespace, but **it's not** an *empty* string.

Comment: @voyger: that's still overkill. do `if (strlen($str)>0 && strlen(trim($str))==0)` if that's what you want. or use `!empty($str)`. why would you bother comparing it to the trimmed string?

Comment: This will be true if your string is empty, ex: $str == "", which you may not want

Comment: @Travis0: That's already been pointed out, but tarnfeld apparently _did_ want to include empty strings.  Still, since people keep wandering by to point it out again, I have edited the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 10):

### from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2992388/160173
If you want to upvote, do it on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2992388/160173), not this one!

---

This will be the fastest way:

```
$str = '      ';
if (ctype_space($str)) {

}
```

Returns `false` on empty string because empty is not white-space. If you need to include an empty string, you can add `|| $str == ''` This will still result in faster execution than regex or trim.

[ctype_space](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php)

---

as a function:

```
function stringIsNullOrWhitespace($text){
    return ctype_space($text) || $text === "" || $text === null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo preg_match('/^ *$/', $string)
```

Should work.

Comment: @stereofrog: I respectfully disagree. Regexes are overkill for something like this, that can be handled perfectly by built in functions.

Comment: That's true, and also maybe builtin functions like shown by John are faster than regexp. But I love regexp, and I use to do everything I can by them, even if not necessary at all. And anyway, I was sure that  simplest solutions will have been posted, I just want people not to forget regexp :D

Comment: always returning 0 for -------- $str = "ffff gggg";
echo preg_match('/^ *$/',$str);

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression:

```
$result = preg_match('/^ *$/', $text);
```

If you want to test for any whitespace, not just spaces:

```
$result = preg_match('/^\s*$/', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

check if result of  trim()  is longer than 0

Comment: will not work ... run ... $str = 'ffffgggg';

if (strlen(trim($str)) > 0)
echo 'space';
else
echo 'nospace';

output is  .. space

Answer (score 3):

I think using regexes is overkill, but here's another sol'n anyway:

```
preg_match('`^\s*$`', $str)
```

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
preg_match("/^[[:blank:]]+$/",$str,$match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chop($str) === ''
```

This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ck-editor then you should do this

```
if( strlen(trim($value,'&nbsp;')) == 0 ){
    echo "White space found!"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way, just for play

```
<?php  
function is_space_str($str) {
    for($i=0,$c=strlen($str);$i<$c;$i++) {
        switch (ord($str{$i})) {
            case 21: 
            case 9:
            case 10: 
            case 13: 
            case 0:
            case 11: 
            case 32: 
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }   
    }   

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in my program it worked well like this,

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$commentcheck = trim($comment);

if (empty($commentcheck)) 
{
    //instruction with $comment
}
```

trim() function just delete all spaces from $comment string.
Then it check if it is empty.
So in this if statement you have to show an error message then use else to code whatever you want to write.

Comment: this answer has been given before, there is nothing new