# Check if string is just white space?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If string only contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352779/if-string-only-contains-spaces)

I do not want to change a string nor do I want to check if it *contains* white space. I want to check if the entire string is *ONLY* white space. What the best way to do that?

Comment: @Dan McG I must suck at searching because I swear I searched for this before I posted it.

Comment: The question may be duplicate, but the answers are not.

Comment: @webbiedave The answers are similar. How many ways do you need to check for a space white space string?

Comment: @Justin Johnson: So if someone comes up with a better way to do it, it shouldn't be added or upvotable?

Comment: No, it should be posted on the first question.  Just because a question has an answer, doesn't mean an alternate or better answer cannot be posted later.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: But with no rep incentive :(

Comment: @Justin Johnson: Maybe we should throw this on meta. I'd be curious to know the consensus on this.

Comment: My thinking is this: Duplicate questions decentralize responses and have negative effects on organization, which is why they have the option to be closed by the community (which I typically encourage in cases like this). However, I have seen questions that ask the same thing but illicit a completely different type of response where it made sense to keep both questions open (looking for link), but this is not one of those.  Rep is nice, but to me it comes second to the organization and consistency of the resource that this community is building.

Comment: Also, the rep that you got for your answer wont go away if the question is closed (99% sure of that), so it doesn't really hurt those who have answered.

Comment: Rep only disappears on deleted questions. BTW, the question sited as an exact dup asks about detecting *spaces*, not *white space*. So the question is not an **exact** duplicate.

Comment: Plus, neither this question nor the other has an answer taking into account Unicode whitespace (preg_match('/^[\pZ\pC]$/u',$str)). Very lame indeed to close just because it seems that it might be a duplicate, while in reality there is just a vague analogy.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This will be the fastest way:

```
$str = '      ';
if (ctype_space($str)) {

}
```

Returns false on empty string because empty is **not** white-space. If you need to include an empty string, you can add `|| $str == ''` This will still result in faster execution than regex or trim.

[ctype_space](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php)

Comment: Wow, I didn't imagine it could get much simpler than the trim, but I guess it can. +1 for a function I've never seen or used.

Comment: Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php 
Check for alphanumeric character(s)
ctype_alpha — Check for alphabetic character(s)
ctype_cntrl — Check for control character(s)
ctype_digit — Check for numeric character(s)
ctype_graph — Check for any printable character(s) except space
ctype_lower — Check for lowercase character(s)
ctype_print — Check for printable character(s)
ctype_punct — Check for any printable character which is not whitespace or an alphanumeric character
ctype_space — Check for whitespace character(s)
ctype_upper — Check for upperca...

Comment: "This will still result in faster execution than regex or trim." < True; http://ideone.com/t8ou8D

Comment: `ctype_space(" ") === false`

Comment: if empty check is needed, use `if (ctype_space($str . ' '))`

Answer (score 49):

since trim returns a string with whitespace removed, use that to check

```
if (trim($str) == '')
{
 //string is only whitespace
}
```

Comment: Hmm, indeed, faster then the preg_* route..

Comment: +1 for a non regex solution. Not that there is anything wrong with regex.

Comment: Just remember that trim will turn anything you pass into it into a string.  i.e (trim(false) == '') will return true, which may fall outside the original poster's requirements (but it most likely fine)

Comment: Can be done faster >  http://ideone.com/t8ou8D

Answer (score 13):

```
if( trim($str) == "" )
    // the string is only whitespace
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

`preg_match('/^\s*$/',$string)`

change * to + if empty is not allowed

Comment: What does `\s` mean? Non white space?

Comment: @John, as said, whitespace, perhaps your confusing the character class ^ ([^p] = anything not 'p') with '^p' (= string has to start with p)

Comment: `\s` is "whitespace," `\S` is "not whitespace"

Comment: I'm voting down only because you should avoid regex only when needed.  For something simple as this, build in PHP functions are the way to go

Comment: @Wrikken, yes thanks. I have never used the \s char, plus I think regex is much easier to write than to read.

Comment: @MANCHUCK: I even voted myself down & ctype_space up, but there were already comments here so I opted not to delete it.