# Form submit even it isn't filled

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have an PHP guestbook. So I can write nothing into the form and submit, then it posts. Can I avoid this?

Here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST["Name"]) &&
    isset($_POST["Email"]) &&
    isset($_POST["Überschrift"]) &&
    isset($_POST["Kommentar"])) {
        $daten = array("überschrift" => $_POST["Überschrift"],
                       "eintrag" => $_POST["Kommentar"],
                       "autor" => $_POST["Name"],
                       "email" => $_POST["Email"],
                       "datum" => date("d.m.Y"));
        $daten = base64_encode(serialize($daten));
        if(!file_exists("gaestebuch.txt")) {
            $datei = fopen("gaestebuch.txt", "xb");
            fclose($datei); 
        }
        $altdaten = file_get_contents("gaestebuch.txt");
        if (file_put_contents("gaestebuch.txt", "$daten\r\n$altdaten") ) {
            echo "Eintrag hinzugefügt!";
        } else {
            echo "Fehler!";
        }
}
```

Comment: Use `!empty` instead of `isset`

Comment: You can use client side and server side validation

Comment: or use javascript to do this, to prevent the form from being submitted

Comment: use isset and !empty for all variables like this if (isset($_POST["Name"]) && !empty($_POST["Name"]))

Comment: @u_mulder okay i will try this

Comment: Please don't overwrite your questions with an answer, it is hard for new readers to understand what the problem was if you ask a question featuring working code. The answer below is more than sufficient.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the information i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the the first value ISSET so you know it is a POST request then check if the rest are empty

```
if (isset($_POST["Name"]) &&
    !empty($_POST["Email"]) &&
    !empty($_POST["Überschrift"]) &&
    !empty($_POST["Kommentar"])) {
        $daten = array("überschrift" => $_POST["Überschrift"],
                       "eintrag" => $_POST["Kommentar"],
                       "autor" => $_POST["Name"],
                       "email" => $_POST["Email"],
                       "datum" => date("d.m.Y"));
        $daten = base64_encode(serialize($daten));
        if(!file_exists("gaestebuch.txt")) {
            $datei = fopen("gaestebuch.txt", "xb");
            fclose($datei); 
        }
        $altdaten = file_get_contents("gaestebuch.txt");
        if (file_put_contents("gaestebuch.txt", "$daten\r\n$altdaten") ) {
            echo "Eintrag hinzugefügt!";
        } else {
            echo "Fehler!";
        }
}
```

also consider using OR instead of &&

```
!empty($_POST["Email"]) OR
!empty($_POST["Überschrift"]) OR
!empty($_POST["Kommentar"]))
```

This means if only one of the fields is empty it will fail instead of only when all of the fields are empty

Answer (score 0):

By nothing do you mean white space?
If so just check so in a if statement. ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992329/check-if-string-is-just-white-space))

```
if (trim($str) == '')
{
    //string is only whitespace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below lines.

```
php > $a = '';
php > echo isset($a) ? 'a is set' : 'a is not set';
a is set
php > echo empty($a) ? 'a is empty' : 'a is not empty';
a is empty
```

setting something doesn't mean that it is not empty. so, use `isset($foo) && !empty($foo)` .

better create a function,

```
function present($x) {
  return (isset($x) && !empty($x));
}
```

and use it.

```
if (present($_POST['foo'])) {
 /* do something */ 
}
```

or do it for whole `$_POST` array,

```
function present($somevar) {
  return (isset($somevar) && !empty($somevar));
}

function all_vars_are_ok($arr) {
  $x = array_map("present", $arr);
  return (array_filter($x) == $x);
}
```

then,

```
if(all_vars_are_ok($_POST)) {
  /*
  *  do something 
  */
}
```

Comment: i now have a solution like isset($_POST["Name"]) && (!empty($_POST["Name"]))

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Your can put attribute `required` in input tag.
2. You can add **JavaScript** validation.
3. In PHP you can check like this: `!empty($variable)`