# Codeigniter "SPACE" when input caused error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Problem: When User enter "Space" in register form , it will still entered into database , how do i prevent it ?

Code I tried: Used trim , but same problem occurred when users only Enter "SPACE", how do i resolve the issue ?

```
$userName=  ($this->input->post("userName"))? trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") : "NIL";
```

Comment: `$userName=  (trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") !="")? trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") : "NIL";` try this

Comment: I think use need to do one more check like is not null or not empty with user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$userName= ctype_space($this->input->post("userName"))? trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") : "NIL";
 ----- OR ------
$userName= strlen(trim($this->input->post("userName")))!=0? trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") : "NIL";
```

You can use ctype_space to check if the string contains only space . Please refer to this question [If string only contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352779/if-string-only-contains-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your are assigning value to `$username` so it will not be null

You can check the value using

```
$userName= (trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") !="")? trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") : "NIL";
```

but this will assign value either ways, if it is null than `$username` will be `NIL` else the input value

Suggestion

```
 $username = "";
if(trim($this->input->post("userName"), " ") != ""){
    $userName= $this->input->post("userName");
    //insert into database
}else{
//redirect with error message
}
```

**Also, use client side and server side validation and check minimum length to that field**

Comment: i did that ,but when user enter "space" it will still enter to database

Comment: did you use any validation?