# defining an empty variable?

Tags: php, string

suppose

```
$test = '';

if(empty($test)){ $test = "not found";}

echo $test;
```

the above case the answer will be "not found"

but below one even though the `$test` variable is empty but result give nothing.

```
$test = ' ';

if(empty($test)){ $test = "not found";}

echo $test;
```

how we can treat both these variables as empty in PHP??

Comment: A string is empty if its length is 0. A string with a single space character has the length 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trim the value before checking it.

It is important to trim before checking it because `empty` only checks variables and not the value you're passing in.

```
$test = trim(' ');

if (empty($test)) { /* ... */ }

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 8):

`$test = ' '` is not empty. From the details in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> The following things are considered to
> be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

If you want to test if `$test` is only white space characters, see these questions:

[If string only contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352779/if-string-only-contains-spaces)
[How to check if there are only spaces in string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754393/how-to-check-if-there-are-only-spaces-in-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could do `if (empty(trim($test))) ...`</strike>

CORRECTED:

`$test = trim($test);`

`if (empty($test)) ...`

Trim removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

Comment: -1 because `empty` only works on variables, not on expressions. This case is explicitly mentioned in the PHP manual that it will *not* work.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why everybody is recommending `empty` here. Then you could just leave it out and use PHPs boolean context handling:

```
if (!trim($test)) {
```

But to actually check if there is *any* string content use:

```
if (!strlen(trim($test))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own function to test this:

```
function my_empty($str) {
  $str = trim($str);
  return empty($str);
}
```

That will treat all strings containing only whitespace as empty, in addition to whatever the empty method already provides.