# Checking to see if a string contains any characters

Tags: php

I would like to check and see if a given string contains any characters or if it is just all white space. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
$search_term= " ";

if (preg_match('/ /',$search_term)) {
    // do this
}
```

But this affects search terms like this as well:

```
$search_term= "Mark Zuckerburg";
```

I only want a condition that checks for all white space and with no characters.

Thanks!

Comment: trim it. if the length of the trimmed string is 0 then it's of all white spaces. has some other characters otherwise :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if there are only spaces in string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754393/how-to-check-if-there-are-only-spaces-in-string-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
if(trim($search_term) == ''){
    //empty or white space only string
    echo 'Search term is empty';
}
```

`trim()` will cut whitespace from both start and end of a string - so if the string contains only whitespace trimming it will return empty string.

Answer (score 3):

[`ctype_space`](http://php.net/ctype_space) does this.

```
$search_term = " ";

if (ctype_space($search_term)) {
    // do this
}
```

The reason your regular expression doesn’t work is that it’s not anchored anywhere, so it searches everywhere. The right regular expression would probably be `^\s+$`.

The difference between `ctype_space` and `trim` is that `ctype_space` returns `false` for an empty string. Use whatever’s appropriate. (Or `ctype_space($search_term) || $search_term === ''`…)