# UTF-8 encoding does not work properly with Internet Explorer but works perfectly with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, internationalization, tooltip, alert

I need to display an alert box in other than English language for which I am making use of bean message using Application Resource properties file. The code written in JSP works perfect in Firefox but in IE the characters are messed up and I get all box signs inside alert box.The same problem occurs for ToolTips as well. Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set servlet encoding?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479383/why-is-ie-failing-to-show-utf-8-encoded-text

Comment: Which version of IE !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did found a solution for my query. Actually the issues were with the tool tips and alert boxes were getting displayed in box sign characters only in Internet Explorer and that too in Windows Xp but working properly in windows 7 and other browsers.
What i did was:

```
1. Right Click On Desktop
2. Properties
3. Appearence Tab
4. Click On Advanced Button
5. In the Item Combo box Select MessageBox(the font combo box should get enabled by then)
6. Select Arial MS Unicode Font instead of Tahoma(Windows XP Default) Font.
```

And then Check. The desired output will be seen. This is a work around solution but it seems to work fine. Thanks WouterH and Hardik for your guidance till here.

Answer (score 9):

Check your page encodings

FF uses UTF-8 page Encoding. View--> Character Encodings

Earlier versions of IE set character encoding according to the language on the client when the document did not specify encoding

Which IE Version are you using ?

This may help also. [IE uses the wrong character set when it renders an HTML page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928847)

Is charset is utf in headers ?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Hi Hardik,
I am using Internet Explorer 8. My actual concern is where my labels are getting displayed proper.
Why only alert boxes display box type characters and that too only in internet explorer.
I need to have a solution for my alert boxes which display box type characters i.e garbage value instead
of which i need to display proper Hindi Font. Any suggestions.??

Comment: Have you set <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Please find the below link for the bug which i am getting in internet explorer. Actually i am using UTF-8 throughout. hindifontcheck.blogspot.in/2012/04/blog-post.html

Comment: Sorry I can't help you further with that screenshot. A live url would be great. Maybe you can put an example online of the problem.

Comment: I had in my page 'utf8', fine in chrome, but bad in ie. 'utf-8' helped. thx