# Wrong character entities displaying in IE11 -- &middot; rendering as &sum; -- is this really a charset issue?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, internet-explorer-11

I designed several UI prototypes (testing initially in Chrome) using HTML5, and while testing in other browsers, noticed that IE11 was substituting different characters for common character entities, like &middot; and &nbsp; on one of the two UI's I was testing.

Both prototypes are hosted on the same server, in different folders, so I'm a bit baffled by the research I've done which points to IE10 & IE11 giving a higher precedence to HTTP over BOM in HTML5; but... if the server was sending out a header declaring ISO-8859-1 or windows-1251, overriding the UTF-8 charset, shouldn't I be seeing the same problem on both prototypes? Wouldn't I see problems with other characters?

The thing that is really bugging me is that, whatever the charset, the HTML character entities in the markup would be the same, right? How does IE manage to misinterpret that?

In any case, I've tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

as well as:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

and:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

and still get † instead of non-breaking spaces, or ∑ instead of ·

I don't have host access to change the .htaccess file, though I will pass that suggestion on to my supervisors. I'm just not sure I have a sound explanation for the way IE is behaving; is this character swapping truly caused by IE failing to recognize UTF-8?

How do I explain this issue appearing in subfolder A but not in subfolder B on the same host, if the problem does result from the HTTP vs BOM prioritization?

Comment: You can't mix 8859-1 and UTF-8. If you use UTF-8 and your stored data was saved in 8859-1, you're kind of screwed.

Comment: Oh, no, I did not have them both at once. I replaced the uft-8 declaration for the ISO-8859-1 as a test, but saw nothing different. Not that I probably would, if the problem is the header sent by the server to IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I failed to present my question clearly, my apologies. To recap, character entities I've used in my markup for years were displaying incorrectly in IE11. My search for a cause led me to several posts on stack overflow and elsewhere that suggested the problem might be due to the way IE puts priority on the HTTP header over the BOM (unlike other browsers).

See: [UTF-8 encoding does not work properly with Internet Explorer but works perfectly with Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999381/utf-8-encoding-does-not-work-properly-with-internet-explorer-but-works-perfectly) (which also recommends: [IE uses the wrong character set when it renders an HTML page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928847)).

However, on checking to see exactly what encoding was being applied to the page, it kept saying UTF-8. So, I put up this question to find out if there was another known cause. I did not get an answer, but I did stumble across on on my own. In a way, the answer is implicit in the answer the author of the post I linked to gave to his own question. I simply did not see it at the time.

Put simply, my "defective" prototype did not have a unicode font declared. I thought I started both prototypes with the same basic css, but... yeah, these things happen. The one thing I didn't check, because I was so confident it did it by rote. I did catch references to the need for unicode fonts in HTML5 in various posts on this (and related) topics, but let me emphasize:

**Be sure to use Unicode fonts with UTF-8 in HTML5**

I'm assuming that browsers other than IE have unicode versions in the font stacks of their default font-families.

Answer (score 0):

Move the order of the fonts from
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
to this 
    body {
      font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,  sans-serif;
in your bootstrap.css