# Different Thai character/font on IE, UTF-8 encoding issue?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding, font-face, meta

When the text appears on IE it has a different character appears like this :

[image: different character]

but when on Chrome or Firefox it looks fine :

[image: the right one]

is it a bug about UTF-8 encoding?
i put these `<meta>` on my `<head>` :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

i need the description is appears like on Chrome or Firefox.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look here:

[UTF-8 encoding does not work properly with Internet Explorer but works perfectly with Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999381/utf-8-encoding-does-not-work-properly-with-internet-explorer-but-works-perfectly)

It could be the problem of encoding in Windows.