# IE not showing encoded text for specific element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a strange issue with Internet Explorer (tested from version 7 and above) and document encoding.

- Document is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM
- Defined encoding within `<head>`

Begin of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

[...]
```

Well, the problem is: Same text in diferent elements show different encode outputs:

HTML and expected result:

```
<h1>Início</h1>
<h2>Início</h2>

Início // Bigger than h2
Início
```

Internet Explorer results:

```
Início // h1 works fine
InÌcio // h2 does not work
```

All other texts works fine. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479383/why-is-ie-failing-to-show-utf-8-encoded-text) but does not have a answer which guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: This sounds very strange. Does it happen if you test a with a page containing nothing but the content shown in the question – without any stylesheets? If yes, can you post a URL of a demo, just to make sure. I cannot reproduce the problem on IE 10 (tested all modes).

Answer (score 1):

Try using an HTML number for your special character: ie. `&#204``;` for Ì.

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it locally, which makes me assume it has to with your local settings. What's your systems' language?

Comment: Just dawned on me; it could also be your browser character encoding settings; is IE set to utf-8 as well?

Comment: While this might be a useful workaround in some cases, it tends to hide the real problem and may cause nasty problems in the future, since the problem would remain unsolved. Moreover, it makes the HTML source less readable.

Comment: Ok, I have done some tests and found that it is an issue with one of my files. When I create a empty html document, all worked well.

Comment: I have found the problem. I have `helvetica` fount defined in CSS, which cause this issue. When I change `font-family` all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the issue only occour whit `helvetica` font defined.

```
h2 {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans','lucida grande', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160%;
}
```

So, I removed from CSS and all worked fine:

```
h2 {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans','lucida grande', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160%;
}
```