# utf8=✓ in rails 3.1 GET forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I use form helper with GET action, the resulting url shows utf8=✓.

It was caused by rails adding a hidden input utf8. My question is is it possible to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove that field? According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) Rails Guides article it's quite useful and helps to overcome issues with some browsers (IE, I believe).

> The first input element with name utf8 enforces browsers to properly
>   respect your form’s character encoding and is generated for all forms
>   whether their actions are “GET” or “POST”.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348524/357743) answer for a nice explanation about why you might need that parameter (previously snowman character was used instead of check mark).