# _utf8 POST parameter on gmail login contains a snowman character

Tags: post, authentication, utf-8, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the _snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-rails-3-forms-for)

If you inspect the POST parameters of [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) login with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) or [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) developer tools, you'll see a `_utf8` parameter with a value of `☃`:

```
_utf8:☃
```

(See the attached image in case your browser doesn't render the value. It's a snowman, U+2603, `http://www.utf8-character.info/#!%E2%98%83`.)

Why do they do this? Is it possible that they somehow test for browser compatibility to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)?

[image]

Comment: bro it's 2012 get a stronger password also change ALL you other accounts on the internet that have also have that password

Comment: @Letseatlunch: Thanks for the advice. As you can see I went into the trouble of bluring the possibly sensitive parts of the request. If you think that I left out my real email and password... well... think again.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The _utf8 header along with a [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character is to ensure that

1. At least one Unicode character is submitted to the server
2. Force certain non-compliant browsers to respect the form's character encoding

In some cases, the `_utf8` header is given a value of a ☃ and sometimes it is a ✓. What it is doesn't really matter and may have arbitrarily been chosen for fun.

Comment: Why do they care to submit at least one unicode character to the server? What difference does it make?

Comment: cherouvim: It may be to ensure that the rest is unicode as well (for instance on old version of IE) rather than some other local encoding.

Comment: Originally in Rails it was a snowman, then they made it a checkmark. It's to force IE to interpret the entire form submission as UTF-8, which it will not do otherwise.

Comment: @StephenOrr: Which versions of IE?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Not sure, and I can't find any definitive answers. I suspect IE6 and below though. This is just what I remember from the discussions going on when the snowman character was originally added.

Comment: Therefore, IE sucks! Don't use it!