# Why Kickstarter applies "utf8=[Unicode character]" to the query string?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I noticed that (for example) when searching on Kickstarter it applies `utf8=[Unicode character]` to the query string, like the following:

[image: Kickstarter and UTF-8]

Is it some fancy way of detecting whether the client supports UTF-8? Never came across this trick before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the \_snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That parameter could be added to force older browsers (IE 6/7) to encode url parameters as unicode.