# Why do Envato Marketplace have utf8=✓ in their search url's

Tags: url, character-encoding

On all of the Envato Market places like AudioJungle, ActiveDen and GraphicRiver.

When you use the search bar the url it goes to contains `utf8=✓`

`http://audiojungle.net/search?utf8=✓&term=dfg`

---

1. Why do they need to declare the charset?
2. Why would they use a tick instead of `true` or `1`?
3. I would expect ✓ to be less browser safe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the \_snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of IE have a problem with proper Unicode handling when submitting forms under certain circumstances. Including a character which must definitely be encoded in one of the Unicode encodings is a hack to trigger the proper behaviour. Just including it fixes the bug, "utf8=✓" is a tongue-in-cheek implementation for this fix.