# Rails search URI with unwanted parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

## Background

I am creating a search field in my header. This code in my view:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <%=f orm_tag( "/search", method: "get", :class=>"navbar-form navbar-left", :role => "search") do %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%=t ext_field_tag :q, nil, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => 'Domain/IP Search' %>
        </div>
        <%=b utton_tag "Search", :type=>'submit', :class=> "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

creates this output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" role="search">
    <div style="display:none">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Domain/IP Search" type="text">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Here is a picture:

[image: search field]

## The issue

The problem is when I search, I get this in my url:

```
/search?utf8=✓&q=test&button=
```

Ideally, I'd like it to be more like:

```
/search?q=test
```

**tl;dr:**

How do I get rid of the button parameter (and hopefully the utf one as well).

### Extra info:

routes.rb

```
resources :search
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = params[:q]
    puts @results.to_s
  end
end
```

search\index.html.erb

```
<%=@results.to_s %>
```

**EDIT, answer**

Adding this because while the accepted answer helped me get to the solution; it didn't have the exact code for my circumstance. I made these changes:

1) routes:

```
match '/search',          to: 'search#index',         via: 'post'
```

2) form in my header:

```
        <%= form_tag search_path, method: "post", :class => "navbar-form navbar-left", :id=> "SearchForm", :role => "search" do %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => 'Domain/IP Search' %>
        </div>
        <%= button_tag "Search", :type=> 'submit', :class=> "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: have you considered using POST instead of GET? it will make sure things don't go in the query string.

Comment: Are there additional implications to using POST instead?

Comment: You'd need to change your route to using POST. otherwise... not really. You wouldn't be able to construct a link to it, without also including method = post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET**

The bottom line, as I wrote in another answer, is that [you're using `GET`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

[image]

Essentially, when you submit a `GET` form, it appends the parameters to your URL, whilst a `POST` form will append the data to the request body (or somewhere hidden).

The difference is just that the `GET` request expects a response to be *returned* immediately, and so you have to pass the parameters in the URL to ensure the server knows how to construct it. The best example being if you use a `GET` request to load a page.

The `POST` method is used primarily used for forms, where a response is not expected immediately; thus allowing you to keep the params hidden in the request.

---

**Fix**

We've actually created a basic search feature [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) (the actual search doesn't work for some reason, but the live search does)

The way we did it was as follows:

```
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'products#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]
```

This will firstly allow you to access the search action by typing `domain.com/search/your-query-here`

In terms of submitting via a form, you'll be able to use JQuery to amend the URL with the input from the text field:

```
#app/views/elements/_nav.html.erb
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :post, :id => "SearchForm" do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search your favourite products or brands', :autocomplete => :off, :id => 'SearchSearch'  %> 
        <%= image_submit_tag('nav_bar/search.png', title: 'Search', class: 'search_submit', data: { "placement" => "bottom" }) %>
<% end %>  

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//Search Submit
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SearchForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if( $('#SearchSearch').val().length > 0 ) {
            var search_params = '/' + $('#SearchSearch').val().toLowerCase();
        }else{
            var search_params = ''
        }

        window.location.href = $(this).attr('action') + search_params
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing with the Utf8 parameter but, Rails is & but its needed. It's to correct some issues in IE's parameter encoding, This parameter was added to forms in order to force Internet Explorer 5, 6, 7 and 8 to encode its parameters as unicode.Its fixes encodeing issue of IE.

Please refer following link:

[What is the _snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for/3348524#3348524)

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is a feature of rails.

It was previously the snowman.

It helps IE to really use utf-8.

Avoid using form_tag and it works:

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get" >
  <%= text_field_tag 'query' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil%>
</form>
```

Now style your form as you want