# Which IE versions need the utf8 enforcer hack (snowman hack)

Tags: internet-explorer, utf-8

I've read [What is the _snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for/3222015) and it says, that rails utf8 checkmark (former snowman) hack is only needed for Internet Explorer.

But I can't find a list, WHICH Internet Explorers require the hack. So it would be good to know, which versions are affected.

The background is, that

1. it looks ugly
2. it confuse users
3. (it seems) some google tools have problems with that (try https://testmysite.withgoogle.com and put in `https://www.google.com?utf8=✓`, it loads forever and aborts after ~5-10 min with `Your site took too long to analyse`)

Comment: Well according to the answer with the most upvotes over there, it is necessary for IE 5 up to and including 8. (But if you were to still support any of those, you’d not be doing the world a favor in the first place.)

Comment: I have removed [tag:ruby] and [tag:ruby-on-rails] tags since the question has nothing to do with both.