# Rails Bootstrap - Remove name attribute from submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following search form I made:

```
          <%= bootstrap_form_for :search, url: admin_panel_users_path, method: 'get' do |f| %>
              <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px; line-height: 25px;">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-center" style="margin-top: 6px; font-weight: bold">
                  <%= f.label :keyword%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <%= f.text_field :keyword, hide_label: true %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <%= f.submit 'Search User', hide_attribute_name: true, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
                </div>
              </div>
          <% end %>
```

However, when I submit, I get a lot of things that I don't need as parameters in my url, and the url then looks like this:

```
?utf8=✓&search%5Bkeyword%5D=&commit=Search+User
```

While I only want the url to be like this:

```
?keyword=mysearch
```

Is there a way to do it with the `bootstrap gem`? And in addition, remove that hidden UTF field it places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass [`enforce_utf8`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) with form as false. It was added in Rails 3 originally to fight IE compatibility issues for a form submitted with `GET` request. It is called as [_snowman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348524/1376448) param.

> :enforce_utf8 - If set to false, a hidden input with name utf8 is not
>   output.

For removing commit parameter, pass `submit_tag` with `name:nil`

```
<%= f.submit 'Search User', name: nil, hide_attribute_name: true, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```